# TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'orientation' when plotting with plt

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had a perfectly fine working script to generate some graphs from a pipeline. However, I then rebooted Docker improperly, and now when I want to call `plt.show()` or `plt.savefig()`, I get hit with `TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'orientation'.`

I'm assuming this is something wrong with the matplotlib backend. I have tried reinstalling all sorts of version of matplotlib but with no effect. I have even tried setting different matplotlib backends

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use(option)
```

with all possible options. Most don't even work, or generate a different error.

I really don't understand how everything was working fine but now isn't. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error after updating to matplotlib 3.6.1.

Returning to version 3.5.2 solved it for me.